# SSRS Report Server with Forms Auth Not Working on a Port other than 80

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

We setup a custom implementation of an SSRS report server to use forms authentication.  Can we use a port other than 80?  We are getting 401 unauthorized when we do use another port other than port 80.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you have a firewall that blocks the other ports.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is 2005 it sounds more like an IIS problem than SSRS, you might post over at Serverfault as well.